# show that $b,c \in \Bbb N$ for $b=c^{\frac{1}{c-1}}$ $\iff$ c = 2.

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to show that $b,c \in \Bbb N$ for $b=c^{\frac{1}{c-1}}$ $\iff$ c = 2. The reverse implication is easy, but the forward implication is tricky. It seems essentially to state the the (n-1)th root of a natural number n is not an integer for n>2.

Comment: If $b = c^{\frac{1}{c-1}}$, then $b^{c-1} = c$. If $b$ and $c$ are integers greater than $1$, then the LHS is, roughly speaking, *really big*.

Comment: @JoeyZou How is this relevant?

Comment: @Did if $b>1$, then the LHS is at least $2^{c-1}$, which is larger than $c$ for $c>2$. So that leaves very few cases to check.

Comment: @JoeyZou *That* (the content of your second comment) is relevant.

Comment: @Did I'll be less coy about my comments in the future then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{x-1}$. Then, $f'(x) = -\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}\ln x + \dfrac{1}{x-1} \cdot \dfrac{1}{x} = -\dfrac{x(\ln x - 1)+1}{x(x-1)^2}$.

For $x \ge 3$, we have $f'(x) < 0$, so $f$ is decreasing on $[3,\infty)$.

Hence, for all $c \ge 3$, we have $f(c) \le f(3)$, i.e. $\dfrac{\ln c}{c-1} \le \dfrac{\ln 3}{2}$.

Exponentiating both sides to get $c^{\tfrac{1}{c-1}} \le \sqrt{3} < 2$.

Trivially, $c^{\tfrac{1}{c-1}} > 1$ for integers $c \ge 3$. Therefore, $1 < c^{\tfrac{1}{c-1}} < 2$ for all integers $c \ge 3$.

Hence, $c^{\tfrac{1}{c-1}}$ is not an integer for any integer $c \ge 3$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

By Bernoulli inequality

$$b^{c-1} \geq 1+(c-1)(b-1)$$

Now note that 
$$1+(c-1)(b-1) \leq c \Leftrightarrow \\
2+bc-b-2c \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
(c-1)(b-2)  \leq 0$$

This leaves very few cases to check.

Answer (score 1):

As Joey notes we have  $b^{c−1}=c$. Let's rewrite this as $b^{d}=d+1$. The left-hand side grows much faster than the right. For $d>1, b>1$, we have $b^d=(1+n)^d = (1 + dn + ...)$ in the binomial expansion where the missing ... terms are $> 0$. But $1+dn+...> 1+d$. Equality is only possible if d=1, meaning c=2, and so b=2.

Answer (score 1):

$1<  c = b^{c-1}\!\Rightarrow\,b\neq 1\Rightarrow\,b\ge 2\,\Rightarrow\,b^{c-1}\ge 2^{c-1} > c\,$ if $\,\color{#c00}{c > 2}\ $ (proof: $\,2^2 > 3\,$ and the inductive step is straightforward $\, 2^{c-1} > c\,\underset{\large \times 2\,}\Rightarrow\, 2^c> \color{#c00}{2c > c\!+\!2}> c\!+\!1)$