# How do I prove that the only integer $x$ for which $x^\frac{1}{x-1}$ is an integer is only $x = 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

It should be a simple problem to deal with but the attempts I have made are unsuccessful. I first tried to solve it by letting $x^\frac{1}{x-1} = pk \hspace{0.1 cm} for \hspace{0.1 cm} some\hspace{0.1 cm}    prime\hspace{0.1 cm} number \hspace{0.1 cm}p$ but I got stuck when I tried to figure out what p had to be. I then tried solving it by assuming that $ x\neq2$ and then writing $\frac{1}{x-1}$ as $\frac{1}{x-2+1}$ and seeing if that would lead to a contradiction or dividing by 0. I could use a hint or some advice

Comment: For a sufficiently large $x$, it is always between $1$ and $2$, so it can't be an integer. You just need to check the smaller cases by hand.

Comment: Check out [show that $b,c \in \Bbb N$ for $b=c^{\frac{1}{c-1}}$ $\iff$ c = 2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861623/show-that-b-c-in-bbb-n-for-b-c-frac1c-1-iff-c-2). Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/) to search for mathematical problems.

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen using **proof by contradiction**

Assume that there exist $x\geq 3$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}=n\in \mathbb{N}$

Therefore $x=n^{x-1}$ and as $x\geq 3$, then $n \neq 1$, but $2^{x-1} \gt x$ $  \forall x \gt 3$, This can be seen by induction

Therefore $n^{x-1} \gt x$ $\forall n \geq 2$

So $\nexists n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}=n\in \mathbb{N} $ for $x \geq 3$

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.